# How to fix java OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space from DataImportHandler?

Tags: java, solr, tomcat7

I am trying to import a large dataset (41million records) into a new Solr index. I have setup the core, it works, I inserted some test docs, they work. I have setup the data-config.xml as below and then I start the full-import. After about 12 hours! the import fails.

The document size can get quite large, could the error be because of a large document (or field) or due to the volume of data going into the DataImportHandler?

How can I get this frustrating import task working!?!

I have included the tomcat error log below.

Let me know if there is any info i have missed!

logs:

```
Jun 1, 2011 5:47:55 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1 call
INFO: Creating a connection for entity results with URL: jdbc:sqlserver://myserver;databaseName=mydb;responseBuffering=adaptive;selectMethod=cursor
Jun 1, 2011 5:47:56 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1 call
INFO: Time taken for getConnection(): 1185
Jun 1, 2011 5:48:02 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [results] webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={command=full-import} status=0 QTime=0
...
Jun 2, 2011 5:16:32 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: Full Import failed:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:664)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:267)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:353)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:411)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:392)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DDC.convertStreamToObject(DDC.java:419)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ServerDTVImpl.getValue(dtv.java:1974)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DTV.getValue(dtv.java:175)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Column.getValue(Column.java:113)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:1982)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:1967)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getObject(SQLServerResultSet.java:2256)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getObject(SQLServerResultSet.java:2265)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.getARow(JdbcDataSource.java:286)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.access$700(JdbcDataSource.java:228)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator$1.next(JdbcDataSource.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator$1.next(JdbcDataSource.java:260)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorBase.getNext(EntityProcessorBase.java:78)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:75)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:591)
    ... 5 more

Jun 2, 2011 5:16:32 AM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback
INFO: start rollback
Jun 2, 2011 5:16:44 AM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback
INFO: end_rollback
```

data-config.xml:

```
<dataConfig> 
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
        driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://myserver;databaseName=mydb;responseBuffering=adaptive;selectMethod=cursor"   
        user="sa" 
        password="password"/> 
  <document> 
    <entity name="results" query="SELECT fielda, fieldb, fieldc FROM mydb.[dbo].mytable WITH (NOLOCK)"> 
      <field column="fielda" name="fielda"/><field column="fieldb" name="fieldb"/><field column="fieldc" name="fieldc"/> 
    </entity> 
  </document> 
</dataConfig>
```

solrconfig.xml snippet:

```
<indexDefaults>
    <useCompoundFile>false</useCompoundFile>
    <mergeFactor>25</mergeFactor>
    <ramBufferSizeMB>128</ramBufferSizeMB>
    <maxFieldLength>100000</maxFieldLength>
    <writeLockTimeout>10000</writeLockTimeout>
    <commitLockTimeout>10000</commitLockTimeout>
  </indexDefaults>
  <mainIndex>
    <useCompoundFile>false</useCompoundFile>
    <ramBufferSizeMB>128</ramBufferSizeMB>
    <mergeFactor>25</mergeFactor>
     <infoStream file="INFOSTREAM.txt">true</infoStream>
  </mainIndex>
```

Java config settings: init mem 128mb, max 512mb

Environment:
 solr 3.1
 tomcat 7.0.12
 windows server 2008
 java: v6 update 25 (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
 (data coming from:sql 2008 r2)

```
/admin/stats.jsp - DataImportHandler
    Status : IDLE
    Documents Processed : 2503083
    Requests made to DataSource : 1
    Rows Fetched : 2503083
    Documents Deleted : 0
    Documents Skipped : 0
    Total Documents Processed : 0
    Total Requests made to DataSource : 0
    Total Rows Fetched : 0
    Total Documents Deleted : 0
    Total Documents Skipped : 0
    handlerStart : 1306759913518
    requests : 9
    errors : 0
```

EDIT: I am currently running a sql query to find out the largest single record's field length, as I think this is probably cause of exception. Also, running import again with jconsole to monitor heap usage.

EDIT: Read [solr performance factors page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors#Factors_affecting_memory_usage). changing maxFieldLength to 1000000 and changing ramBufferSizeMB = 256. Now for another import run (yay...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DDC.convertStreamToObject(DDC.java:419)
```

makes it pretty obvious that The MS JDBC driver is running out of ram. Many JDBC drivers can default to fetching all their results at once in memory. So see if this can be tuned or consider using the opensource JTDS driver which is generally better behaved anyway

I don't believe maxfieldlength is gonna help you - that will affect how much Lucene truncates, but not how much is initially transferred. Another option is to only transfer a selection at a time, say a 1 million, using TOP and ROWNUMBER and such for paging.

Comment: "Many JDBC drivers can default to fetching all their results at once in memory" - Thats why I have 'responseBuffering=adaptive;selectMethod=cursor' on the driver to stream in batches to avoid OOM.

Comment: Well, fair enough, but is it an absolute no go not to give jtds a shot?

Comment: A mix of upping the memory & JTDS worked! 

For people finding this in the future... dump the MS SQL driver! I tried it with more memory (1.25gb) and it failed.

I then setup the JTDS driver http://jtds.sourceforge.net with the following connection string:
"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://mymachine/mydb;useCursors=true;useLOBs=false;" and it worked wonderfully.

I also found the param 'useLOBs' critical in our import, otherwise it doesnt store the raw data for large string fields, instead it just stores 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ClobImpl@xxxxxx'

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully import a large table using jdbc to Sql Server without running into out of memory errors by batching the queries manually.  In my case, in 256 batches:

data-config.xml:

```
<dataConfig> 
  <dataSource  
      type="JdbcDataSource" 
      driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://myserver;databaseName=mydb;responseBuffering=adaptive;selectMethod=cursor"   
      user="sa" 
      password="password" 
      autoCommit="true" 
      batchSize="10000" /> 
  <document> 
    <entity 
        name="batch"
        query="
          with Batch as (
            select 0 BatchId
            union all 
            select BatchId + 1
            from Batch
            where BatchId < 255
          ) 
          select BatchId FROM Batch OPTION (MAXRECURSION 500)
        "
        dataSource="JdbcDataSource"
        rootEntity="false">
      <entity name="results" query="SELECT fielda, fieldb, fieldc FROM mydb.[dbo].mytable WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE CONVERT(varbinary(1),fielda) = ${batch.BatchId}"> 
        <field column="fielda" name="fielda"/><field column="fieldb" name="fieldb"/><field column="fieldc" name="fieldc"/> 
      </entity> 
    </entity> 
  </document> 
</dataConfig>
```

The parent entity **batch** is a recursive sql server CTE that returns byte values 0-255.  This is used to filter the child entity **results**.

**Note 1:** The where condition (ie. **CONVERT(varbinary(1),fielda) = ${batch.BatchId}** ) should be adjusted depending on the type and contents of the partitioning field in order to partition the results into equal batches.  e.g. Use **fielda % 255 = ${batch.BatchId}** if *fielda* is a number.  In my case *fielda* was a uniqueidentifier so the first byte was sufficient.

**Note 2:** The **rootEntity="false"** on the **batch** entity is required and indicates the **batch** entity is **NOT** a root document.

Answer (score 1):

For mysql, it works

As per solr wiki,

DataImportHandler is designed to stream row one-by-one. It passes a fetch size value (default: 500) to Statement#setFetchSize which some drivers do not honor. For MySQL, add batchSize property to dataSource configuration with value -1. This will pass Integer.MIN_VALUE to the driver as the fetch size and keep it from going out of memory for large tables.

Should look like:

```
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" name="ds-2" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/mysqldatabase" batchSize="-1" user="root" password="root"/>
```

Comment: hi, the original question was for MS SQL

Answer (score 0):

> > Your java config settings might be not enough for this job: init mem 128mb, max 512mb

Try this cargo cult fix for OutOfMemoryError: increase heap size 
make it -Xmx1024M or more if you can afford that and initial 512M -Xms512M

Comment: yep. that is the simplest thing to do. gonna also try using JTDS as MJB suggests

Answer (score 0):

I've found that with large record sets things can get a bit hairy.  You do have a couple options.

The Quick and most likely best option would be to allocate more memory to the indexing system!  Memory (for the most part) is pretty cheap.

The other thing I might try is [chunking the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972056/chunked-urldatasource-for-solr-dataimporthandler).

Depending on the size of your "documents" 41M docs may bog you down when it comes to searching.  You may want to shard the documents.  When using DIH I try to facilitate partitioning using querystring parameter.  You can do this by referencing the appropriate parameter passed into DHI using the ${dataimporter.request.MYPARAMETERNAME} within the query statement.

Comment: chunking is interesting but seems like a lot of work/overkill. i'm curious how long it took to write the wrapping api around it? or if u are interested in open sourcing/gist it?

Comment: Cant open source it... about 4 hours of real work to write the wrapper